# Lambda and Generic Methods

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I am learning Lambda and I came across something I cannot solve.

Originally my code was:

```
package Lambdas;

@FunctionalInterface
interface NumericFunc2 {
    <T extends Number> T func(T n);
}

class Lbd_488_NumericFunc_SelfTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // This block lambda returns the smallest positive factor of a value.
        NumericFunc2 smallestF = (n) -> {
            double result = 1;
            // Get absolute value of n.
            n = n < 0 ? -n : n;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++)
                if ((n % i) == 0) {
                    result = i;
                    break;
                }
            return result;
        };
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 12 is " + smallestF.func(12));
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 11 is " + smallestF.func(11));
    }
}
```

However, **I keep getting errors next to my operators (`<`, `-`, `/`)**.
PS:**Even if I change it to `<T extends Double>` I get the same errors.**

Now, if I change the code by adding the parameter type, I get **an error saying that the "Target Method is Generic"**:

**Even if I change it to `<T extends Double>` I get the same errors.**

```
package Lambdas;

@FunctionalInterface
interface NumericFunc2 {
    <T extends Number> T func(T n);
}

class Lbd_488_NumericFunc_SelfTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // This block lambda returns the smallest positive factor of a value.
        NumericFunc2 smallestF = (Double n) -> {
            double result = 1;
            // Get absolute value of n.
            n = n < 0 ? -n : n;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++)
                if ((n % i) == 0) {
                    result = i;
                    break;
                }
            return result;
        };
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 12 is " + smallestF.func(12));
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 11 is " + smallestF.func(11));
    }
}
```

But, **if I change the class from non-generic to generic, everything works fine**, like this code:

```
package Lambdas;

@FunctionalInterface
interface NumericFunc2<T extends Number>  {
    T func(T n);
}

class Lbd_488_NumericFunc_SelfTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // This block lambda returns the smallest positive factor of a value.
        NumericFunc2<Double> smallestF = (n) -> {
            double result = 1;
            // Get absolute value of n.
            n = n < 0 ? -n : n;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++)
                if ((n % i) == 0) {
                    result = i;
                    break;
                }
            return result;
        };
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 12 is " + smallestF.func(12));
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 11 is " + smallestF.func(11));
    }
}
```

So, my question is. What I am doing work on my first part of the code? How can I use lambdas with generic methods, inside non-generic classes properly?

Comment: tip- dont write noisy code(more then one line) inside `{}` in lambada use `methods()` instead

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you *cannot* do this sort of numeric operation on a `Number` object.  There is no way; **this has nothing to do with lambdas and everything to do with the `Number` abstract class just not providing those features.**

There is not even any way to get the absolute value of a `Number` without knowing what kind of `Number` it is.  You can't see whether it's positive or negative, you can't negate it, you can't add, subtract, or multiply it.  The *only* thing you can do with a `Number` is convert it into another primitive type, but you can't convert it back and you can't do math with it.

Comment: Alright, I understand your point. However, if I change from "Number" to "Double", I still get the same error.

Comment: In addition, as stated in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3 you can see that _A lambda expression is congruent with a function type if all of the following are true: ...  The function type has no type parameters_ so a lambda can't be assigned to a functional interface which contains type variables in the function signature (which is not the same as having a generic functional interface)

Comment: Your interface also doesn't mean what you think it means.  
When you write `<T extends Number> T func(T n);`, what you're saying is every implementation of the interface (including the lambda) must have an implementation of `func` that works for _any_ `T extends Number`.  Your interface wouldn't let you have an implementation for just one subtype of `Number` even if you weren't using lambdas.

Comment: How could I write this code in a way that works? Keeping the method generic and the class non-generic?

Comment: @Jack's link says that you _cannot_ do this with lambdas.  You might do it with an anonymous class, if you dealt with the issue of `Number` not being able to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3), generics and lambdas won't work together. [This eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482441) discusses it with some code examples.

In order to make it work, you have to fall back to [anonymous inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). I.e. you have to write the full `new NumberFunc() {...}` mambo-jambo around your function.

I had to make some other changes in the body of the method to make it compile:

- `result` is the boxed `Double` so I can cast it to `T`
- inside of the method I'm using the doubleValue() of n because primitive operators won't work on `T extends Number`.

**Putting it together:**

```
class Lbd_488_NumericFunc_SelfTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // This block lambda returns the smallest positive factor of a value.
        NumericFunc2 smallestF = new NumericFunc2() {
            public <T extends Number> T func(T n) {
                Double result = 1d;
                // Get absolute value of n.
                double nAbs = n.doubleValue() < 0 ? -n.doubleValue() : n.doubleValue();
                for (int i = 2; i <= nAbs / i; i++)
                    if ((nAbs % i) == 0) {
                        result = (double) i;
                        break;
                    }
                return (T) result;
            }
        };
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 12 is " + smallestF.func(12));
        System.out.println("Smallest factor of 11 is " + smallestF.func(11));
    }
}
```